# How to install zabbix-agent 3.4 on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, zabbix

I'v tried to install zabbix-agent 3.4 on Ubuntu 20.0 using this way:

```
# wget https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix-release/zabbix-release_3.4-1+bionic_all.deb
   # dpkg -i zabbix-release_3.4-1+bionic_all.deb
   # apt update
# apt install zabbix-agent
```

but it turn to be zabbiz-agent 4.0 has been installed

What is right way to install zabbix-agent 3.4 on Ubuntu 20.0?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you want a previous version, instead of the more recent one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in Ubuntu `focal`, `apt` try to install the highest package version. You should specify the needed version to `apt`.

`apt policy zabbix-agent` Will print:

```
     1:4.0.17+dfsg-1 500
        500 https://mirror.csclub.uwaterloo.ca/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
     1:3.4.15-1+bionic 500
        500 http://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/3.4/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

To install the zabbix-agent v3:

```
sudo apt purge zabbix-agent
sudo apt install zabbix-agent=1:3.4.15-1+bionic
```